# how to use javascript localStorage to save user choices and display in a different html page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a school project, the url is http://angelaalarconcreative.com/LB_v3/
I want to be able to save the user's food choices so that when you click on SAVE it automatically directs you to a different HTML page where the food choices and their combined nutrition facts are compiled together. My teacher gave me this code as a "hint" but I feel more lost than ever staring at her code. Could anyone help me please? :)

```
$(function() {

$("#save-meal").click(function(){


    var authenticated = localStorage.getItem("Greetings");
    alert(authenticated);
    if(authenticated == null) {
        //alert saying you need to login to use this feature
        alert("You need to login to use this feature!");
    }
    else {

        var openDiv = "<div> Welcome " + document.write(localStorage.getItem("Welcome")); 

        var calories = " <div> Calories : " + document.write(localStorage.getItem("calories")); 
        var totalFat = " <div> Total Fat : " + document.write(localStorage.getItem("totalFat")); 
        var cholesterol = " <div> Cholesterol : " + document.write(localStorage.getItem("cholesterol")); 
        var sodium = " <div> Sodium : " + document.write(localStorage.getItem("sodium")); 
        var dietaryFiber = " <div> Dietary Fiber : " + document.write(localStorage.getItem("dietaryFiber")); 
        var sugar = " <div> Sugar : " + document.write(localStorage.getItem("sugar")); 
        var protein = " <div> Protein : " + document.write(localStorage.getItem("protein")); 


        var closeDiv = "</div>"  
    }

});
```

});

I want to know how to use localStorage to get the user's random choices and to retrieve it in a different page. What is the proper syntax for that given the interactivity of my project?

UPDATE: I've changed the JS a little bit according to your answer however it still doesnt work! I suspect faulty syntax. Can someone help me? I feel like I'm so close to getting it!!!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#save-meal").click(function(){
    var calories = $('.nf__table #value--calories').text();
    var totalfat = $('.nf__table #value--total-fat').text();
    var cholesterol = $('.nf__table #value--cholesterol').text();
    var sodium = $('.nf__table #value--sodium').text();
    var fiber = $('.nf__table #value--dietary-fiber').text();
    var sugar = $('.nf__table #value--sugar').text();
    var protein = $('.nf__table #value--protein').text();

    localStorage.setItem('value--calories', calories);
    localStorage.setItem('value--total-fat', totalfat);
    localStorage.setItem('value--cholesterol', cholesterol);
    localStorage.setItem('value--sodium', sodium);
    localStorage.setItem('value--fiber', fiber);
    localStorage.setItem('value--sugar', sugar);
    localStorage.setItem('value--protein', protein);
});

$("#gotosave").click(function(){
    document.write(localStorage.getItem('value--calories'));
    document.write(localStorage.getItem('value--total-fat'));
    document.write(localStorage.getItem('value--cholesterol'));
    document.write(localStorage.getItem('value--sodium'));
    document.write(localStorage.getItem('value--fiber'));
    document.write(localStorage.getItem('value--sugar'));
    document.write(localStorage.getItem('value--protein'));

});
```

});

//document.getElementById("#saved-items").innerHTML = calories;

Comment: Do you need to use localStorage? You could easily pass the data in the url. If you want to use localStorage you need to set the data you want to save when you click on save, then redirect and in the new page retrieve the data as in that example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow.

You can learn more about localStorage (or sessionStorage) from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).  Determine which one is most appropriate for your application.

When your user drags a bunch of food to the 'dinner plate', your `.nf__table` (nutrition facts table) is updated with a bunch of values. At this point, when your user clicks on the save button, you want your Save event handler to basically grab the values in `.nf__table` and do a `localStorage.setItem()` to store the values in local storage.

For example, this is how you would store the amount of calories in localStorage:

```
var calories = $('.nf__table #value--calories').text();
localStorage.setItem('value--calories', calories);
```

When the user is directed to the next page, your document-ready handler can then retrieve the stored values using `getItem()` and update the DOM with those values:

```
localStorage.getItem('value--calories');
```

So, the idea is that the nutrition fact values are "remembered" on the first page, so that they can be retrieved on the next page.

Comment: you're amazing! Thank you for being to clear in explaining this. I understood this better than my teacher's explanation!